# Mono: ViewEngine unable to find Index in ~/Views/Home/

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mono

I'm currently using ASP.NET MVC 4 in conjunction with an Nginx server and fastcgi-mono-server4. After attempting to any Views, I get:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
    ~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
    ~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
    ~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
    ~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
    ~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.Web.Mvc.
Exception stack trace:
  at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext context) [0x00000] in           <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext context)   [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter (IResultFilter filter,   System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext preContext, System.Func`1 continuation) [0x00000] in <filename    unknown>:0
```

However, I would like to note that it works locally on IIS. In addition, I checked that everything was being deployed and restarted the server but this error persists. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe file paths in NGINX are case-sensitive, unlike IIS.